# Eschewmenical Counseling

Tags: discussion, blog

Got another dumb idea for the blog.

What if we took on some of the softer, more personal, pastoral (or pastorale) questions and addressed them on the blog from a range of perspectives? I think this would give more clarity into how Christians of all traditions can draw on the truths that they gain through the Scripture and Tradition.

Not directly answering questions, but providing relevant materials for Christians dealing with specific problems.  Like a complicated walk through for some elder scrolls game on arquade, except for real life.

---

**Awesome!** +5; -2 = good enough for meta.c.se amiright?

So now to the droll task of soliciting blog post ideas....

How about we just skip that and write about

- Spiritual Dryness
- Death

and

- Addiction

and move on to the "who is on board" and "light up the chat, please" phase?

Comment: Can you describe this more? What would this look like exactly?

Comment: I could actually see this working!

Comment: "First you need to talk to the grumpy wizard who will give you the potion to defeat the dragon in the spooky forest..."  As long as authors have actually walked the path and gotten through, I don't see why this wouldn't be a good idea.  I find it _way_ more valuable to hear from someone who has experienced a hardship than from someone who has studied it in school.

Comment: @JonEricson is that a commitment?  I'd like to read a nice monograph in dealing with twins from an Evangelical perspective.

Comment: I'd really be leery of this. I understand the impulse, but it is going to be very easy for people to misconstrue what this is about and what is said. Hypotheticals make for bad case law, dangerous medicine, and horrible advice.

Comment: considering this was one of the original purposes for site specific blogs (SO/prog.se's soft questions were a specific thing mentioned in the original blog post IIRC). I'm on board with giving it a shot.

Comment: @AffableGeek Is there, perhaps, a way to do this without using hypothetical examples? Perhaps real live case studies or a historical only approach?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that even the most innocuous topic can be collaboratively answered given the differences between the various lenses through which Christians of different stripes approach the issues.

For example, you suggested a topic of "spiritual dryness." A conservative Biblical literalist (as I once was) may suggest [*spending more time in the Word*](http://trinitybaptistbergamo.blogspot.com/2011/03/gods-solution-to-overcome-spiritual.html) or [*repent of secret sin*](http://thedisciplers.com/5reasons-for-spiritual-dryness/). Someone with a more liberal leaning may suggest [*spending time serving among the poor*](http://www.stpaulsfay.org/id264.html). The rare [Christian pantheist](http://www.pantheism.net/paul/history/gospel.htm) may think that *a long walk in the woods* is just the thing.

I suspect that there will be a broad range of opinions, rather than consensus, on each topic. If I am mistaken, would you be willing to demonstrate how the topics will be addressed in a manner that appeals to Christians of all stripes?

Or, on the other hand, are you suggesting a panel-type approach in which the distinct views of the various creeds are represented independently? If so, would you elaborate on the planned format?

Comment: If you were talking about the main site these ideas might be relevant, but we're talking about Eschewmenical -- the blog project here. The whole premise behind that is leaving echumenicalism behind and **specifically** having folks with differing views do write ups from their own views. There is no expectation of consensus, in fact it is a necessary premise to the whole exercise that the issues covered don't have consensus.

Comment: yeah, we just write completely independently of each other and see what happens.  We had a good thing going last year, but it petered out a bit in the last few months.